# JQuery Mobile App- Updating href attribute in Navbar link updates to 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

So I am creating a survey app and depending on one survey page's selected options, one of two pages will be loaded once a user clicks 'Go'. In determining which link to load into the go button's href property, I also assign the link to a future survey page's 'back' button... I am confused about why this is returning undefined as I am doing the exact same thing earlier in the application and the back button's link is returning the correct link...

So after calling setSurveyFromSurvey5a(), once a user taps 'go' from survey5a,  console.log($("#survey5bback").attr("href")) returns 'undefined', even after it should have been assigned within setSurveyFromSurvey5a()... it will pass the conditional to set the href value, but it just isn't changing it and I'm not sure why...

Here is my code:

**relevant javascript:**

```
    function setSurveyFromSurvey5a(){
        if(goto5a){
            survey5adata.alo_wthfam = translateCheckBox($("#checkbox-alo_wthfam").prop("checked"));
            survey5adata.alo_wthpart = translateCheckBox($("#checkbox-alo_wthpart").prop("checked"));
            survey5adata.alo_wthwork = translateCheckBox($("#checkbox-alo_wthwork").prop("checked"));
            survey5adata.alo_wthfr = translateCheckBox($("#checkbox-alo_wthfr").prop("checked"));
            survey5adata.alo_wthoth = translateCheckBox($("#checkbox-alo_wthoth").prop("checked"));
        }

        //set go and back buttons:
        if(survey5adata.alo_wthfam == 2){
            goto5a1 = true;
            console.log("within survey5adata.alo_wthfam == 2");
            $("#survey5ago").attr("href", "#survey5a1");
            $("#survey5bback").attr("href", "#survey5a1");
        }
        else if(survey5adata.alo_wthfam == 1){
            console.log("within survey5adata.alo_wthfam == 1");
            goto5a1 = false;
            $("#survey5ago").attr("href", "#survey5b");
            $("#survey5bback").attr("href", "#survey5a");
        }

        console.log("#survey5ago:" + $("#survey5ago").attr("href"));
        console.log("#survey5bback:" + $("#survey5bback").attr("href"));
    }
```

**The html from survey5a, survey5a1, and survey 5b:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="survey5a">
    <header data-role="header" data-theme="c">
        <img src="img/evl_logo2.png" class="evllogo" width="100"/>
        <img src="img/uic_logo2.png" class="ui-btn-right" width="100"/>
    </header>
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
        <p>Tobacco Use Interview</p>
    </div>



    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="survey5acontent">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#survey4">Back</a></li>
                <li><a href="#main">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="survey5ago" onclick="setSurveyFromSurvey5a()">Go</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- LINKED SURVEY5a1 -->

<div data-role="page" id="survey5a1">
    <header data-role="header" data-theme="c">
        <img src="img/evl_logo2.png" class="evllogo" width="100"/>
        <img src="img/uic_logo2.png" class="ui-btn-right" width="100"/>
    </header>
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
        <p>Tobacco Use Interview</p>
    </div>



    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="survey5a1content">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#survey5a">Back</a></li>
                <li><a href="#main">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#survey5b">Go</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- LINKED SURVEY5b -->

<div data-role="page" id="survey5b">
    <header data-role="header" data-theme="c">
        <img src="img/evl_logo2.png" class="evllogo" width="100"/>
        <img src="img/uic_logo2.png" class="ui-btn-right" width="100"/>
    </header>
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
        <p>Tobacco Use Interview</p>
    </div>



    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="survey5bcontent">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <!-- Need to determine how to go back correctly -->
                <li><a href="#" id="#survey5bback">Back</a></li>
                <li><a href="#main">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#survey6">Go</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have a typo in your HTML markup:

```
<li><a href="#" id="#survey5bback">Back</a></li>
```

Should be

```
<li><a href="#" id="survey5bback">Back</a></li>
```

Remove the '#' from the id.

Comment: Ah yes I discovered this late last night. Thanks!